# How to detect sufficient format(data type) for QImage to consume minimum RAM?

Tags: c++, qt, image-processing, computer-vision, qimage

I want use minimum RAM when i load Image in [QImage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html) in Qt, if we don't have any information about Dpi or type(RGB16 or RGBA32 or...) of image in image header.

Any idea or code or method to detect automatically image type like ([QImage::Format_RGB32](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#Format-enum) or [QImage::Format_RGB16](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#Format-enum) or...) for [QImage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html)?

Comment: Just let the image loader pick a format. It will be the most natural internal format for the external image format read. Usually RGB32 for opaque images. You can also call QImageReader::format() to guess the format, so you can prepare a suitable QImage for it, but that only saves the allocation inside the image-decoding plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [QImage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html) is inheriting [QPaintDevice](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpaintdevice.html). It's not a binary format of an image nor contains or anything else like that. Imagine it as a piece of memory with some methods and member properties that can explain the content of that memory or how you can draw pixels on that piece of memory. For example, the method [QImage::load](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#load) will use the [QImageReader](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimagereader.html) instance to load an image file like JPG, PNG, BMP, etc and initializes everything needed for [QImage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html) to hold that data. [QImageReader](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimagereader.html) can automatically detect image format.
You will then be able to convert this [QImage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html) instance using [***QImage::convertToFormat***](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#convertToFormat) method.

```
QImage img;
img.load("/some/path/to/sample.png");
QImage converted = img.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_RGB16);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer with details. Do you think that  QImageReader correctly detect best format for image ?

Comment: @RashedDIP, actually it will not decide what format to choose. It will use the format of your file. Being ```best``` format does not mean anything here. QImage is not a format. It's a class to keep an image in memory.
You can also instantiate an empty QImage with your desired width/height and start painting on it using QPainter. Then you can save it to a file using QImage::save method. I recommend you to read the documentation of QImage carefully.

Comment: Sorry, i think some misunderstanding happened. My speak about "Format" is data type that mentioned in [qt website](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.12/qimage.html#Format-enum)

Comment: @RashedDIP, I just wanted to clarify. QImageReader will create the QImage with an appropriate format. For example for a PNG file that has an alpha channel, it will choose the format which has an alpha channel. It's up to you to convert your format to your desired format if you know what you want.

Comment: I know you are telling about format type in general like(jpg or png), but format type in qt tell about data type that i give you link address in previous comment like( RGB16 or RGB32)

Comment: @RashedDIP, the format depends on how you initialize your QImage. QImageReader will do it automatically if you are filling the QImage from a file. If you choose to create an empty QImage, you can decide what format to choose depending on your requirements. Each file, regardless of its binary format or compression mechanism, has a pixel format as well which is what we are talking about now.